# Declare a variable as Decimal

Tags: excel, vba, types, decimal, excel-2007

I'm optimizing a macro in VBA which had none of the data types declared, so everything was clumsily treated by the compiler as a variant. I'm dealing with scientific measurements, so I need precision.

How do I declare `Dim decAsdf as Decimal` (not like that but the proper way)?

Answer (score 24):

You can't declare a variable as `Decimal` - you have to use `Variant` (you can use `CDec` to populate it with a `Decimal` type though).

Comment: For example: `Dim v: v = CDec("123456789.123456789")`

Comment: So then is every decimal declared on a different line?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. The declaration is the `Dim` which is no different from any other variable type.

Comment: Would this be a correct example: Dim decMeanComp: decMeanComp = CDec("1234")

Comment: Yes. Just to clarify - the declaration and assignment don't have to be on the same line, I just can't post separate lines of code in a comment!

Answer (score 4):

To declare a variable as a `Decimal`, first declare it as a `Variant` and then convert to `Decimal` with `CDec`. The type would be `Variant/Decimal` in the watch window:

[image]

[Considering that programming floating point arithmetic is not what one has studied during Maths classes at school](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), one should always try to avoid common pitfalls by converting to decimal whenever possible.

In the example below, we see that the expression:

`0.1 + 0.11 = 0.21`

is either `True` or `False`, depending on whether the collectibles (0.1,0.11) are declared as `Double` or as `Decimal`:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim preciseA As Variant: preciseA = CDec(0.1)
    Dim preciseB As Variant: preciseB = CDec(0.11)

    Dim notPreciseA As Double: notPreciseA = 0.1
    Dim notPreciseB As Double: notPreciseB = 0.11

    Debug.Print preciseA + preciseB
    Debug.Print preciseA + preciseB = 0.21 'True

    Debug.Print notPreciseA + notPreciseB
    Debug.Print notPreciseA + notPreciseB = 0.21 'False

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to declare the variable as a `Single` or a `Double` depending on the precision you need.  The data type `Single` utilizes 4 Bytes and has the range of -3.402823E38 to 1.401298E45.  `Double` uses 8 Bytes.

You can declare as follows:

```
Dim decAsdf as Single
```

or

```
Dim decAsdf as Double
```

Here is an example which displays a message box with the value of the variable after calculation.  All you have to do is put it in a module and run it.

```
Sub doubleDataTypeExample()
Dim doubleTest As Double


doubleTest = 0.0000045 * 0.005 * 0.01

MsgBox "doubleTest = " & doubleTest
End Sub
```