# Test if value is Long or Integer (no decimal places)

Tags: excel, vba, integer, long-integer

I need to test if the value in textbox1 and textbox2 is integer or long (with no decimal places).

I tried something like this:

```
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer

    x = TextBox1.Value
    y = TextBox2.Value

    If x = Int(x) Then
        'my code
    Else
        MsgBox("value is not an integer")
```

If I put x=2.3 it does not display MsgBox but it rounds the value to 2.

Comment: I would check if `TextBox1.Value` is an integer because at the time you are setting `x` the value is rounded. `x` will stay an integer whereas `TextBox1.Value` doesn't have to be one.

Comment: oh, I didn't think of that. It works perfect now , Thank you

Comment: Normally, you could assign the value to an integer (with implicit truncation of decimal digits), reassign to a floating point number and compare to the source. Alternatively, compare the source number with its Rounded value. If the same, integer, otherwise it has decimal digits.

Comment: @Bathsheba just sent the same solution I mentioned above.

Comment: @FDavidov: Yup that's not such a bad approach although it will break down after the 52nd power of 2. Btw, do think about reforumulating your comments to an answer: I'll upvote.

Comment: @Bathsheba, YOU already gave a good answer. It is your post that should be upvoted, not mine (yes, we thought about the same solution, but you posted it first, so the honor should be yours :-)).

Comment: Not at all: SO works well if there are selection of answers. The conversion in and out of a floating point double is a different and effective approach.

Comment: One more thing: if the solution breaks above 2^52, it would appear that the code is for astrophysics and not earthy things. Hence, VBA might not be the right platform.

Comment: OK. You convinced me. I'll post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've specified the *type* of `x` to be an `Integer`, the conversion from the text box string to the `Integer` has already taken place. Hence `Int(x)` is a no-op.

One fix would be to use something like

```
If IsNumber(TextBox1.Value) Then
    If Fix(TextBox1.Value) = TextBox1.Value Then
        'I am an integeral type.
    End If
End If
```

Here, `Fix` truncates a numeric type, and I'm relying on VBA to make the correct comparison. Note that VBA doesn't implement a *short-circutted* `And` so you need to use a nested `If` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can't `Dim var as Decimal` in VBA but you can `Dim var as Variant` and use `var = CDec(...)` to store a decimal data type in a variant.  Even then, I've found that decimals with 14 or 15 zeroes after the decimal followed by a number (or the equivalent decimal subtracted from a whole number) are rounded to a whole number.  I haven't found a solution yet that differentiates tiny decimals from whole numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach (pseudo-code, so check syntax!)

```
Dim l_Temp_D1 as Decimal
Dim l_Temp_D2 as Decimal
Dim l_Temp_I  as Integer

l_Temp_I  = TextBox1.Value
l_Temp_D1 = TextBox1.Value
l_Temp_D2 = l_Temp_I

if (not IsNumber(TextBox1.Value)) then
    ' Error!!!
End If

if (l_Temp_D1 = l_Temp_D2) then
  ' Integer
  ...
else
  ' Float
  ...
End If
```

Comment: VBA doesn't have a `Decimal` type. If you refactor that, I'll certainly upvote.

Comment: I guess you will need to find the way to upvote twice: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xtba3z33.aspx (:-)).

Comment: I'm not so sure yet; note this is VBA not VB.

Comment: Let's make it three times... ( :-) + :-)): http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=339929&seqNum=2

Comment: Ha. But check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30917438/vba-how-to-declare-as-decimal. It appears to be possible in Access VBA but not Excel VBA.

Comment: Please read the first line of my answer: _(pseudo-code, so check syntax!)_. I rest my case.