# How to round a number with 2 digits with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

I would like to copy a number from one to another worksheet. The copied number may have more than 2 digits after the decimal. I am using this code:

```
Dim MyLimit As Single
MyLimit = Round(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Y1").Value, 2)
Debug.Print MyLimit
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("AB2") = MyLimit
```

Debug.Print is showing 0,93.

The Value of Cell AB2 is showing "0,930000007152557".

How do I get the correct value of 0,93 into the cell AB2?

Comment: Don't declare it as a float type (`single`). Floats are, by their nature, imprecise. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30917438/declare-a-variable-as-decimal)

Comment: Thx thats it. It is working with "Dim MyLimit".

Comment: `Dim MyLimit` will declare it as `Variant`, Change it to `Dim MyLimit As Double`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Correct me if I'm wrong, but Double is also a Float type and could very well lead to imprecision once again. I think, in that link I shared, the solution is to declare as a variant and set using `CDec()` to ensure precision. I haven't run into this exact issue with a float in VBA before, so that may not be 100%

Comment: Use the round function... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/round-function

Comment: Set it as a variant and then add a watch on `MyLimit`. See what datatype, vba considers it as :) @JNevill

Answer (score 1):

Use *Decimal* (or Currency):

```vb
Dim MyLimit As Variant
    
MyLimit = CDec(Round(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Y1").Value, 2))
```

However, `Round` is quite buggy and also performs *Banker's Rounding* which may not be what you want. A simple method to perform normal *4/5 rounding* is to use `Format`:

```vb
Dim MyLimit As Variant

MyLimit = CDec(Format(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Y1").Value, "0.00"))
```

For extended and/or extreme rounding, study [VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round).